# Yii2 Image validator throws an error if it is not image file

Tags: php, image, validation, yii2

I have a simple validator for image file input which looks like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['thumbnail', 'image', 'minWidth' => 800],
    ];
}
```

But if I try to send a txt file, it does not show an error message, but the `ImageValidator` throws me an error:

> PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> getimagesize(): Read error!

Why does this happen? Why does it not stop on the image rule and why does it call `getimagesize` if it is not an image file? How can I suppress it?

[image: screenshot with an error shown]

Comment: I suggest to report this as a bug at https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2 - validators should not throw exceptions when input is invalid, that is the point of validators to avoid such errors.

Comment: It is not an exception it is notice. But in development mode it blocks the view.

Comment: Yii treats all notices as exceptions, so it is still a bug.

Comment: @rob006 please, refer to the [official guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) on when not to add tags to question titles - prefixing the title with the name is not a natural occurrence of the tag name in the title. That said, it's not my intention to cause another prolonged debate about that - the current rendition of the title looks ok to me.

Comment: Yes this title is ok. But it could be better if there is a - after Yii2. All because of search engines. They love keywords.

Comment: @Čamo - and I don't know how do you think people search for questions. Here, take a look at search results for a very simple search with the current title with your question exactly in the [search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTTbV.png). If you are still unconvinced, I can remove it completely from the title again, wait for Google to recrawl, and make a screenshot again. The tag does not have to be in the title to be searchable.

Comment: I am not a member of "people"? PS  This is not about if you can. This is about if you should do it. As all decisions in the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few times I have this workaround:

```
['thumbnail', 'image', 'minWidth' => 800, 'when' => function($model) {
    $check = @getimagesize($model->thumbnail->tempName);
    if( !$check ) $model->addError('thumbnail', 'File is not an image.');
    if( !$check['mime'] || !in_array($check['mime'], ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg']) ) $model->addError('thumbnail', 'File is not jpeg.');
    return $check ? true : false;
}],
```

BUT the correct form is

```
['thumbnail', 'image',
    'extensions' => ['png', 'jpg', 'gif'],
    'mimeTypes' => ['image/*'],
    'minWidth' => 800],
```